# PHP: How to check if DateTime object has time set?

Tags: php, datetime

How can I check if a DateTime object concerns a date or a date+time?

I can check if the time is zero, but I don't know how to distinguish between the instances `$date` and `$datetime` if `$date = new DateTime('2022-09-01')` and `$datetime = new DateTime('2022-09-01 00:00:00')`. `$date == $datetime` results in `true`.

I was looking for something like `$date->containsTime()` but found nothing.

Is it possible to distinguish the two, or are they really absolutely equivalent?

Comment: I don't see any difference there. I think, internally the DateTime object is based on the UNIX timestamp (and since PHP 7.1 the microseconds).

Comment: I was afraid of that. If you do a dump_var they seem exactly identical. Just hoped there was a backdoor somewhere.

Comment: For what reason do you need this? Maybe we can find another way to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, there are other fairly easy ways. However, like there is a difference in MySql betwen TIME DATE and DATETIME I wanted to just as easily make the same distinction once this data has been read into an array with `mysqli_result::fetchAssoc` (after which we convert cols in that array that are in the DB in DATE/DATETIME format to `new DateTime($col)`.)

Comment: I added one of these fairly easy solutions as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to distinguish a date from a datetime, if you are willing to set an extra property while creating the instances.

```
$a = new DateTime('2020-01-01');
$a->type = 'date';
$b = new DateTime('2020-01-01 00:00:00');
$b->type = 'datetime';
var_dump( $a == $b ) ;
var_dump( $a->type == $b->type ) ;
```

results in `true` and `false` respectively.

Comment: This approach is likely to break in a future version of PHP, where adding properties dynamically becomes forbidden. A better idea would be to have a custom class with the DateTime (or, better, DateTimeImmutable) object as one property, and the "type" as a second property.

Comment: @IMSoP Instead of having a custom class with two properties, I would just inherit the DateTime class to a maybe "DateTimeExt" class and just add the "type" property in there. So you have all the features of the DateTime class at once and don't have to refer to a second property. But maybe that's just an issue of taste.